# how does logrotate actually works

Tags: linux, logrotate, log-rotation

I am trying to the setup log for the httpd server then I write a script in `/etc/logrotate.d/apache.conf`

```
/var/log/httpd/* {
    daily
    rotate 3
    size 20K
    compress
    delaycompress
}
```

what I understood from this file

`/var/log/httpd/*` = where all the logs the stored and you want to logrotate them

`daily` = when you want to rotate the log

`rotate`= only 3 rotated logs should be kept

`size` = when your log file size meet with this condition

`compress`= make a zip file of rotated logs

`delaycompress` = kind of compress don't know much

so I hit to apache server that generates a lot of logs

[image: size]

after the log generated

[image: show]

where is my log are store how it is run only on when size condition matches or else
thanks for any guidance or help

one more thing when and how log rotate run why some people suggested to use cron job with logrotate

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the commands and output **as text** formattes as code blocks instead of showing screenshots. Is the error message about the missing file `access_log.4.gz` the last output? If not, show the missing output. Please also show the resulting file after you ran `logrotate`. Please edit your question to answer, don't use comments for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> where is my log are store

Unless you specify the `olddir` directive, they are rotated within the same directory that they exist.

> how it is run only on when size condition matches or else

If you specify the `size` directive, logs are only rotated *if* they are larger than that size:

> size size
>
> > Log files are rotated only if they grow bigger then size bytes.

Files that do not meet the size requirement are ignored (https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate).

> why some people suggested to use cron job with logrotate

`logrotate` is just an executable; it does not handle any facet of how or when it is executed. `cron` is typically how `logrotate`'s execution is scheduled. For example, on CentOS, inside the `/etc/cron.daily` directory is an executable shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/sbin/logrotate -s /var/lib/logrotate/logrotate.status /etc/logrotate.conf
EXITVALUE=$?
if [ $EXITVALUE != 0 ]; then
    /usr/bin/logger -t logrotate "ALERT exited abnormally with [$EXITVALUE]"
fi
exit 0
```

This script is executed one per day by cron and is how `logrotate`'s execution is actually initiated.

Couple other problems:

1. `/var/log/httpd/*` - Unless you're rotating files out of the original directory with the `olddir` directive, *never* end your logrotate's directory definition with a wildcard (`*`). This definition is going to glom on to *every* file in that directory, *including* the files that you've already rotated. Logrotate has no way of keeping track of what files are actual logs and which are stored rotations. Your directory definition should be something like `/var/log/httpd/*_log` instead.
2. You should be reloading `httpd` after you rotate the log files, else it will probably continue to log into the rotated file because you never closed its handle.

   ```
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /bin/systemctl reload httpd.service > /dev/null 2>/dev/null || true
    endscript
   ```

Again this is a CentOS-specific example.